# DotnetCore : OnException method in a custom filter is called two times

Tags: exception, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am using dotnet core and have created a custom exception filter to handle exceptions. The problem i face is that in case of exceptions , the onException method in the custom filter is called two times. Below is the code :

```
   public class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
     {
            public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
                 {
                    // Code 
                    base.OnException(context);
                 }
     }
```

Controller Code is :

```
         [CustomExceptionFilter]   
         public class MyController : Controller
         {
             // Raise an exception in any apis
         }
```

Why onException is called two times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Visual Studio I created a new Asp.Net Core Web Application and used the standard Web Application Template.  Then I added the `CustomExceptionFilter` class and added the `[CustomExceptionFilter]` attribute to the `HomeController` and threw and exception inside it's `Index` method:

```
[CustomExceptionFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new Exception("Time to bail!");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Finaly, I set a breakpoint on this line in the `CustomExceptionFilter`:

```
 base.OnException(context);
```

And ran the website.  The debugger stops on the `throw` of course, and then it stops on the line with the breakpoint.  The breakpoint is only hit once.  So my setup verifies the expected behavior.

**Troubleshooting**
In the past, I have ran into similar situations where something that should only be called once is called twice and it's almost always turned out to be because a second http request came in that I wasn't expecting.  So it really was only being called once per http request.  One way to check on that is to look at the path and query in the method which you can do as indicated below:

```
 public class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context) {

        //set breakpoing on the following line to see what the requested path and query is
        string pathAndQuery = context.HttpContext.Request.Path + context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

        // Code 
        base.OnException(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another scenario that can cause this is adding the attribute in two places:

I had this:

```
config.Filters.Add( new StandardExceptionHandlingAttribute() );
```

AND this:

```
  [StandardExceptionHandling]
  public async Task<int?> ....
```